# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Configuring Authentication with Services.Configure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, configuration, asp.net-core-2.0

The [microsoft docs example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?tabs=aspnetcore2x) shows how to configure using `PostConfigurationOptions` but in this scenario if the configuration were to change the [`GoogleHandler`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google/GoogleHandler.cs) `IOptionsMonitor` dependency will not receive the update.

AFAIK you should be able to just configure the options but I must be doing something wrong as I get the following exception:

```
ArgumentException: The 'ClientId' option must be provided.
Parameter name: ClientId
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthOptions.Validate()
```

I have recreated the problem in a fresh ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web Application:

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace TestWebApplication {
    public class Startup {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            services
                .AddAuthentication(o => {
                    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie()
                .AddGoogle()
                .Services.Configure<GoogleOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google"));

            services.AddMvc(o => {
                o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build()));
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()
               .UseStaticFiles()
               .UseMvc(routes => {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace TestWebApplication {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build()
                .Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
    "Authentication": {
        "Google": {
            "ClientId": "xxxxxx",
            "ClientSecret": "xxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

If I use `services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsMonitor<GoogleOptions>>().CurrentValue.ClientId` the clientId is configured correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [`AuthenticationBuilder.cs`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationBuilder.cs) implementation solved it.

`AuthenticationSchemeOptions` is a named dependency so it should be configured like so:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(o => {
         o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddGoogle()
    .Services.Configure<GoogleOptions>(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google"));
```

Comment: Just in case someone stops by here in the future ... this should be the updated link ... https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationBuilder.cs.